# How can validate form fields in Back-End and show them on Angular7?

Tags: angular, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to write my app back-end side with spring boot and front-end side with angular. I would like to check the information in the form fields on the Back-End side for security. To try this work, I first created a model named Visitor.java and all codes are as follows.

Visitor.java

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class Visitor {

    @NotNull(message = "This field cannot be null.")
    @Email(message = "Invalid.")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "This field cannot be null.")
    private String password;

    public Visitor() {
    }

    public Visitor(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Visitor{" +
                "email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

SignIn.java (RestController)

```
import com.demotest.example.demotest.model.Visitor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin
public class Sign {

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> signIn(@RequestBody @Valid Visitor visitor, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            System.err.println("error!");
            Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
            for (FieldError error:bindingResult.getFieldErrors()){
                errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }
        System.err.println("nice!");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

sign-in.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  model:loginViewModel = {
    email:'',
    password:''
  };

  sendLoginViewModel():void{
    //alert(this.model.email);
    let url = "http://localhost:7070/api/signin";

    this.http.post(url, this.model).subscribe(
      res => {
        //location.reload();

      },
      err => {
                   console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

export interface loginViewModel{
  email:string;
  password:string;
}
```

sign-in.component.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="col-lg-4 card mx-auto px-0">
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col mx-auto text-center" style="font-size: 23.1px; padding-right: 37px; padding-left: 37px;">
          www.sss.com
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col mx-auto text-center" style="font-size: 40px; padding-right: 37px; padding-left: 37px;">
          Welcome
        </div>
      </div>

      <form #f="ngForm" (submit)="sendLoginViewModel()">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col mt-5 px-0 mx-auto">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col mx-auto">
              <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder=""
                     name="email"
                     [(ngModel)]="model.email"
                     #name="ngModel"/>
              <mat-icon matSuffix>email</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>

<!--            todo: Error div i will be added here.-->

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col px-0 mx-auto">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col mx-auto">
              <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password">
              <mat-icon matSuffix>lock</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>

            <!--            todo: Error div i will be added here.-->

          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="col py-1 mx-auto mt-3 mb-3" mat-flat-button color="primary">
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**console.log(err);**

I want to use the following `error: {email: "Invalid."}` On the html page. `email` is the title of the error and `"Invalid."` is the contents of the error message. Because these log fields are sent by Back-End, they are secure information and I want to use them on the html page. How can I write in the  *If there is an email in the error message, print the message.* ?

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 406, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:7070/api/signin", ok: false, …}
error: {email: "Invalid."}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:7070/api/signin: 406 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 406
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:7070/api/signin"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Currently I am able to verify on the background in spring but I cannot print error message on sign-in.component.html. I'm confused to print incoming error information. How do I print the error message?

Comment: I don't get your issue : do you know not know how to use `<mat-error>`, or do you not know how to transfer the error messages from the backend to the frontend ?

Comment: Actually, I don't know either. I'm starting to look at <mat-error> right now. I would appreciate it if you share a material with Spring-boot / Angular.

Comment: That's not how it works, that's on you to provide a [mcve] of your issue, so that I can tell you what is wrong in it. I don't code for you !

Comment: I'm sorry for writing in a complicated way. I updated my sharing and tried to write in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to sub scribe to the error and then us ngif.

```
error: any;

sendLoginViewModel():void{

    let url = "http://localhost:7070/api/signin";

    this.http.post(url, this.model).subscribe(
      res => {
        //location.reload();

      },
      err => {
    this.error = err.message
      }
    );
  }


        <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger">
            {{error}}
        </div>
```

But I would suggest using reactive forms to creating a form group to setting Validators required for the login info.  Then if an error is returned by the server you can set the form control to dirty to envoke ui error state.  You can set the validators.pattern for the email and let the client do basic email validation first like so:

```
this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({

    email: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
    ]))
});


<div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].invalid && (angForm.controls['email'].dirty || angForm.controls['email'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].errors.required">
            A valid email is required.
          </div>
        </div>
```

I would also strongly suggest looking into a more sophisticated authentication example that uses an injectable Auth Guard Service and an alert component.

Here is a good example:
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/29/angular-7-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Comment: My problem is very simple, thank you for making me realize. And this video series also helped me. For those who want to review the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpQWOknO7ZE&list=PLF0fAweo0KojhRilxBEmgIFjv3cbgbQks&index=6